# Unable to ssh tunnel while connected to VPN

Tags: network, ssh

I am trying to SSH tunnel in a guest VM that will connect to a VPN and give access to the host to otherwise blocked urls. All access is correct regarding keys.

- Host = Connecting via the ssh tunnel (Linux)
- Guest = Connects to VPN and is being tunneled to. (OSx 10.13)

Guest has 2 network cards.

1. **VPN network**

   1. IP: 192.168.238.130
   2. Router: 192.168.238.130
   3. DNS Server: 192.168.238.2
2. **Host Only network for the tunnel**

   1. IP: 192.168.138.130
   2. Router: Empty
   3. DNS Server: 192.168.138.1

## No connection to VPN

When I am not connected to the VPN I can connect to the guest very easily:

```
hutber@hutber ~ $ ssh -L 3333:github.someprivateurl.net:22 hutber@192.168.138.130
Password:
hutber@Jamies-Mac ~ $ //ssh access to guest
```

## When connected to VPN

```
hutber@hutber ~ $ ssh -L 3333:github.someprivateurl.net:22 hutber@192.168.138.130
.... (hangs)
```

Comment: Can you connect (no tunnel) to your host via SSH?

Comment: I cannot. I can't connect at all when the guest is connected to the VPN.

Comment: Your VPN provider (work perhaps?) is blocking SSH.

Comment: Interesting... I actually have this same image at home and it works perfect. However at work I connect through a "guest" wifi network, which I then connect to the VPN. The `guest` network connects to ssh without a problem.

Comment: A question then, I am not trying to access external ip's, just my `host` to access the `guests` network. I guess the VPN could block port 22? Even though at home with the same setup they don't block port 22 from working.

Comment: I wonder if i'm able to set up ssh to another port and connect to the vm guest from the host that way

Comment: If it works fine on one and not another, it's the VPN provider who's blocking traffic.  You can definitely change the port and you'll have to do so in the sshd config.  However, it's highly likely that the network admin has closed off all ports and allowed only a select few rather than the opposite of allowing everything and only blocking selected ones

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79152/discussion-between-jamie-hutber-and-allan).

Comment: I have changed the port successfully and connect when not in the VPN via the new port, but when in the VPN its the same problem.

Comment: See my last comment re: network admin blocking ports

Comment: :) Then I am a little confused, as once I connect to the VPN, it doesn't matter where I connect from. At least this is my understanding. Thanks for helping btw

Comment: So I guess the only question left to ask is, is it possible to add an exception/rule to will allow me to connect and bypass the VPN as the two machines are technically physically connected.

Comment: Theres no way to get round the port blocking? Just keep changing ssh's port?

Comment: If you don't control the VPN, you can't get around the end point policies (i.e. routed traffic, blocked traffic, etc.)

Comment: Ah I see. Sad times then. Whats the most confusing is this works at home with the same VPN settings and VPN client... well the same VPN and the same VM image too. The only difference is the `guest wifi` at work

Comment: Thanks Allan. So I can confirm 100% that while at home, connecting to the SAME vpn, that the tunnel is working. So it cannot be the VPN that is blocking it at work.